# How to find the total number of records in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet with below data:

[image: Excel]

How to find the Total Number of records automatically. That is, if we add another record, say "J" to the sheet, then Total Number of records must be automatically updated to 10.

I've tried using COUNT and COUNTA formulas. But there is no use. Any suggestions?

Comment: How does this becomes "off topic - hardware related question"? Stack Overflow has lot of "users" who does not know what is a programming question and a question. Funny..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine `COUNTA` with `COUNT` like this:

```
=COUNTA(A3:A11)-COUNT(A3:A11)
```

[image]

---

- COUNT – this Excel function returns the number of cells in a range that contain numbers
- COUNTA – this function returns the number of cells that are not empty

We know that the number of cells that contain text (not numbers!) is equal to the number of non blank cells – the number of cells containing numbers. In other words: COUNTA – COUNT. Src: http://www.excel-2010.com/count-the-number-of-cells-with-text-in-excel/